# PHP: Get the number of parameter a function accepts

Tags: php, function

Is there any method for finding the number of parameters a php function will accept, 
Like

```
pow - 2   
strlen - 2   
sqrt - 1
```

I have dome some research and got to `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters`. But it seems `ReflectionMethod` needs a `class` and a `method`. Here i don't have a class object.

Also I cannot use `func_num_args` method since for that I have to be inside the method, which is not possible.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php  Based on the first comment it can do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, this may meet your requirements...

```
 $info = new ReflectionFunction('sqrt');
 #print $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
var_dump(
  $info->getName(),
  $info->getNumberOfParameters(),
  $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()
);
```